# Get Nested DataGrid Rows to fill inner Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a nested datagrid in another datagrids column as seen in the image below. This column is the Initial / Date column.

[image: 1]]
I would like the inner datagrid bottom row to fill the inner datagrid to the same size as the outer datagrids row height so that the grey area at the bottom of the inner datagrid is filled.

I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
        <Style x:Key="DataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, AncestorLevel=2},Path=ActualHeight}"/>
    </Style>
```

How can I get it so that the grey area is filled in and the column splitter fills to the bottom as well?

thanks Callum

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this one myself. I created a background image with a border down the centre of it as I had set the widths of my 2 columns to 50% and added this background as a resource to my project. I also set the borderbrush on the datagrid to transparent and set the gridlinesvisibility to none and added the following code:

```
<DataGrid.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Background.png"/>
                            </DataGrid.Background>
                            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Cheers Callum